# Macro to to copy cols and append beneath other cols works but need search to be: "xlWhole" Have: "xlPart"

Tags: excel, vba

I finally got this to work but there is one last problem it searches for `xlPart` and I need it to search for `xlWhole` but I can not figure out where to add the `xlWhole`

Thanks

```
Sub MoveUnder()
Dim ar As Variant
Dim er As Variant
Dim i As Variant
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim LR As Long


Sheets("XXX").Select

    ar = Array("Target", "Label")     ' Find column to copy
    er = Array("Source", "user name") ' Find column to paste beneath


LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
On Error Resume Next
   For i = LBound(ar) To UBound(ar)
       j = Rows(1).Find(ar(i)).Column
       k = Rows(1).Find(er(i)).Column

         Range(Cells(2, j), Cells(LR, j)).Copy _
           Destination:=Range(Cells(LR, k), Cells(LR, k)).Offset(1, 0)
   Next i
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
j = Rows(1).Find(ar(i), Rows(1).Cells(Rows(1).Cells.Count), , xlWhole, xlByRows).Column
k = Rows(1).Find(er(i), Rows(1).Cells(Rows(1).Cells.Count), , xlWhole, xlByRows).Column
```

I added the `After` and `SearchOrder` argument as well.
This will search the 1st Row starting from the 1st entry which is Cell A1.